# Dielectrics between charges

Tags: forces, electrostatics, dielectric

Why does inserting a dielectric of dielectric constant $k_e$ have an effect of increasing the distance from $r$ to $r+t(\sqrt{k} -1)$ in Coulomb's law of electrostatics (where $t$ is the thickness of dielectric slab)? Shouldn't the dipole forces cancel out?

Comment: Hi. Please make your question more clear. You are talking about effect on what?

Comment: Hi. Can you add some diagram etc. to make the question more clear? Which dipole forces are you talking about? And what are you referring to?

Comment: What does "bw" mean?

Comment: @PM2Ring Between